# Rigging a horseshoe crab to move realistically without animating every keyframe?

Tags: animation, rigging

So I have this horseshoe crab model which I sculpted and I need to animate ALOT of different times travelling through scenes and spaces. I created this super basic rig which allows me to control the rotation of the connected body and the tail, but I have to keyframe each part everytime it need to turn/rotate. This ends up looking really clunky and is also super time consuming for each crab/scene.

I have created an IK rig for the crab so the head controls the body as it turns, but I am still struggle to get the motion/rotation to work in any way. I am wondering if there is a sloution to this, to control all sections, motion and rotation, using a rig?

I've put in some mesh images and the crab rig for reference! Thanks!

[image: rig]
[image: wire]
[image: mesh]

Answer (score 2):

For Animation definately you will want a much lower poly mesh. That would be way too many verts to be moving at once!

I'd suggest you retopo the model down so it's a much more manageable in the animation workflow as the first step. There is no way that that mesh is going to deform correctly as it is at the moment!

Next you'll need a better rig, 2 bones will result in just 1 joint hence why your animation will end up looking clunky. Making a rig with at least 4/5 bones in the tail would be ideal. You can set your leading bone to the 'head' since I'm guessing this will be solid (I'm not familiar with the movement of these crabs sorry!)

You will also want to look into the non linear animation workflow! So you can set the animation once then just copy the whole animation track and move it along the timeline as needed! NLA makes it generally much easier to work with

Mainly look at videos of it in action! Reference is a must.